# How to install Doxygen GUI on Ubuntu?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I can't figure out how to install the Doxygen GUI (doxywizard) on Ubuntu. Where can I get it?

Comment: See also: [Ask Ubuntu: How to install Doxygen on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291874/327339). I mention how to install the GUI [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502796/327339).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Debian the package is called doxygen-gui. It must be the same in Ubuntu, so try `sudo apt-get install doxygen-gui`.

Edit : apparently, doxygen-gui doesn't exist in Karmic. Try any other repo ? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=doxygen-gui

Comment: to start doxygen gui type in terminal type `doxywizard`. For diagram perhaps need also `sudo apt-get install graphviz`.

Comment: It confuses me every time I install a package via the CLI and it has some executable name which is not derivable from the package name. :(

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-file search doxywizard
```

is a good way to answer this type of question, and leads directly to `doxygen-gui`.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the older package from Jaunty on Karmic.  I believe it was from this link: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/jaunty/doxygen-gui  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and from what I've read it will become available again in Ubuntu Lucid Lynx , 10.04
(see: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/doxygen/1.6.2-0ubuntu1 )

Downloaded .deb-file from :
https:// launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/doxygen-gui/1.6.2-1
But that needs some libqt4-xml version higher then the jaunty jackalope 9.10 repository .

Guess we'll have to wait a bit .

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse there is a plugin called [eclox](http://home.gna.org/eclox/) which would do the trick.

(tested it in ubuntu 9.04)